# CodeSign error: code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 4.2'

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

What does the following error mean;

CodeSign error: code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 4.2'

I only get the error when trying to test on device..
How to fix this?

Comment: you need to have an iOS developer account and a provisioning profile for your device to install your applications to a device.  installing to the simulator is free and simple

Comment: You should have made an answer with this, as it's perfectly correct...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@hmthur:  You would find your solution in either of these links.

These are the links you can refer to as they too discuss the same problem as you have.

http://davidbits.blogspot.com/2010/11/codesign-error-code-signing-is-required.html

and

http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1061459

As far as I know, it is something to do with setting your active executable as Simulator and not device if you don't have developer license.

Also in some cases it is the problem with the code signing identity as discussed in one the links above.

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you have Targets (not Project) selected when you are editing Build Settings - Code Signing.  Then under Debug, all of the options must be set to the Provisioning Profile for your particular bundle identifier, and under Release all of the options must be set to the Distribution profile of your particular bundle identifier.

Answer (score 0):

If you run xcodebuild from a `Build Phase` `Run Script` or Pre- or Post action in the schemes in another target, and you copy the environment variables, this problem might occur also.

To fix this, run xcodebuild without the environment variables like so:

```
/usr/bin/env -i xcodebuild <xcodebuild arguments>
```

Compiling and running a target during the build phase of another target is used when a coredata store needs to be prefilled before archiving.